# Precarious employment in academia: Why is there no labor union in academia?

Tags: phd, job-search, job

Many positions in academia are precarious, when it comes to employment common behavior in academia would never be acceptable in industry. This applies equally to PhD students as well as to junior academics:

1. PhD students are not guaranteed employment at university
   after working there for 5 years.
2. PhD students are paid little considering their degree: In
   Germany e.g. it is common practice for professors to only pay
       half-time posts.
3. It's common practice for young academics to work well beyond 40 hours even for PhD students that are
   only paid half-time posts. Work regulations regarding maximum worked hours and weekends are often ignored.
4. Junior academics are unlikely to land an unlimited full-time job at a
   university. Directly after graduation this is impossible and even after years of more precarious work as a postdoc only a fraction get unlimited employment.
5. With exception of CS and engineering very little universities care about providing an exit strategy for junior academics and PhD students after academia. (While change in industry is possible in quite a few fields, proper (additional!) training would be much needed.)

These issues are well known. Fundamentally academia is producing too many PhD students and too little full-time positions (not just professorships) for their respective fields which causes much of the mentioned problems.

I feel like the passion almost all young academics and PhD students have for their subject brings a lot of naivety when it comes to employment conditions, which is exploited.

**Why is there no movement inside academia trying to change these working conditions or a push to establish labor unions?**

Comment: Actually there is. But this is country specific

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum: I'm a bit puzzled by the way in which the question was framed to be honest - I was expecting a related but different question about the precarious employment status of junior academics (e.g. postdocs, stipendiary/non-stipendiary lecturers, etc.) The answer to this question seems more straightforward - PhD students are students, not employees, and the PhD is a degree course for them. No-one would normally guarantee a student a job at the end of their course. Also, people often don't want their PhD students to stay afterwards - they want them to spread their wings.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz In many countries, the majority of PhD students are employees (for example, all of North Europe).

Comment: You might not like it much if you were _just_ considered an employee as a PhD student. For example, you might be able to be told what you can study, even the field. You might be told that for this term, no studies for you and you have to teach full time. Union strikes would occur, perhaps, and then you would have no studies and no pay. Think about _all_ of the consequences before you rant.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz As already mentioned a PhD student is not just a student, but especially an employee. I made the question more inclusive to junior academics in general though, as it is focused on an issue that both PhD students as well as junior academics face: A lack of unlimited full-time positions.

Comment: @Buffy Obviously you can't just study whatever you want. You are paid to do research, not any research, but the research you are given a grant for. Because of this it also seems unlikely that the university wouldn't allow you to research. After all they want results and receive new grants. Concerining your last sentence: As we know from lots of different work areas union strikes benefit the employees and don't hurt them.

Comment: Since you mention Germany, both Verdi and GEW are labor unions that specifically also cater to PhD students an young academics. It's just that almost none of those people seem to care or want to join those unions.

Comment: Why should PhD students be guaranteed a job after 5 years?

Comment: @Azor Ahai: Moreover, what non-academic jobs have such guarantees? If anything, the existence of tenure suggests that the argument partially goes the other way.

Comment: @mlk Yes this is what's most disturbing to me. This is why I said in my answer there is lots of naivety when it comes to employment in academia. Many young scientist seem to think "this is the way it always has been, and always will be". I think especially in Germany things could change if the political pressure increases. Many non-academic people don't know about these issues, mainly because young academics are very bad in representing themselves.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Well in many EU countries you have protection against dismissal after you worked for a longer period at a bigger company. You can still be fired of course, but not for reasons like "there is this younger worker that does exactly the same job as you, but for half the price". Being fired on such grounds is e.g. illegal in Germany.

Comment: In Germany there is "Gewerkschaft Erziehung und Wissenschaft", a Union for employees in science and education. They don't have much leverage in Academia, though.

Comment: All graduate student employees at my institution in the US are represented by a union, though participation is optional (not sure how many do pay dues), called a teacher's assistant union but has since branched out.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I guess my perspective was too UK-specific - to the best of my knowledge, I wasn't an employee as a PhD student, and I don't know of any university in the UK where PhD students are employees. The UK may be an outlier in Northern Europe as far as this is concerned (or it may not, and I may not know all the facts).

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum I think it's quite country-specific - in the UK, to the best of my knowledge, PhD students don't count as employees. (Indeed, according to http://www.npc.org.uk/page/1101153773, "The UK is quite unique in considering PhD researchers purely as students.") Broadening the question to focus on junior academics (e.g. postdocs) as well is welcome though - there is a definite sense in which academia can seem quite akin to a Napoleonic era navy, in that there are too many eager lieutenants for the ships available.

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum "Obviously you can't just study whatever you want. You are paid to do research, not any research, but the research you are given a grant for." <-- That depends strongly on your source of funding, and to some extent on the flexibility or otherwise of your supervisor. Some PhD students are luckier than others in this regard.

Answer (score 8):

> Why is there no labor union in academia?

Some universities have unions, others do not.  The scope of the unions varies.

> Why is there no movement inside academia trying to change this?

Many people support changing academia, so the premise of this question is wrong.  The reality is that change is hard, especially when the old system obtains lots of cheap labor.

> how successful have they been in the past?

Unionization usually results in an increase in pay and job security, but the change is small.

For problems 1-5, the solution is simple:  Don't get a PhD.  As long as many people try to get PhDs, economic forces will encourage these problems to persist.

Answer (score 5):

The first question is whether PhD students are union members, or can be. Very often they can but are not. In the UK, a work contract that is separate from the student component is not required to join a union, and membership can be free. In the Netherlands, I think that a PhD student is considered a full-time university employee, with everything that entails for union participation, labour rights etc. Local union braches have participated in dispute resolution at a department level, although PhD students do not receive too much attention.

Beyond that, the situation is too country specific. As a blanket statement, and inaccurate in many cases, PhD students see themselves as students and are not informed or interested in becoming unionised, universities find the flexible dual employee/ student status convenient (again, this does not apply if a PhD student is contractually considered an employee) and unions do not have much to gain, in their opinion, and focus on more important disputes.

I also disagree with the way many points are framed because it is either wrong or a misrepresentation, particularly (1) and (5). I recognise important problems in the position and compensation of PhD students in academia, summarised by "cheap fresh meat" or "scientific proletariat", but this is one of the poorest descriptions I have encountered. A PhD holder is not automatically a good academic or a good colleague.

***EDIT*** - [An exemplary discussion](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109259/improving-work-conditions-of-student-assistants-phds-postdocs-etc?rq=1) from 2018 on the same broad issue.

Comment: I recently joined the UCU, a UK academic staff union. I'm a PhD student and there was no requirement to be a paid TA to join. Plus, membership is free if you're a student.

Comment: @astronat thank you, I will correct my post

Comment: I was under the impression that a PhD student needs some sort of work contract other than being a student.

Answer (score -2):

> These issues are well known. Fundamentally academia is producing too many PhD students and too little full-time positions

More precisely, academia is not making money. We're not even trying to make a profit, where would the money come from?

> Why is there no movement inside academia trying to change these working conditions or a push to establish labor unions?

Union of what? Union would only make senese if there is money to pay salary, but it isn't the case in academia.

Comment: Academia is state funded in many countries with billions of euros.